# ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended ORA-06512:

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-server-2008, oracle11g

What is wrong with this ,
I get this error

```
OLE DB provider "OraOLEDB.Oracle" for linked server "hades" returned message "ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended
ORA-06512: at "SAAP.EDI", line 1416".
OLE DB provider "OraOLEDB.Oracle" for linked server "hades" returned message "ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended
ORA-06512: at "SAAP.EDI", line 1416".
Msg 7320, Level 16, State 2, Line 2
Cannot execute the query "select * from table(edi.ftCustomerCatalog('010','145','000164'))" against OLE DB provider "OraOLEDB.Oracle" for linked server "hades".
```

Code:

```
function ftCustomerCatalog(comno varchar2,cpls varchar2, cuno varchar2) return tblCustomerCatalog pipelined 
is
  c sys_refCursor;
  r recCustomerCatalog;
  sq varchar2(3000);
begin
  sq:='select  
        a.comno
        ,a.t$cpls
        ,coalesce(a.t$cuno,b.t$cuno) as t$cuno
    ,a.t$cpgs,a.t$item
        ,a.t$Upcd
        ,a.t$dsca
        ,a.t$wght
        ,a.t$ship
      ,coalesce(b.t$stdt,c.t$stdt,d.t$stdt,e.t$stdt,f.t$stdt) as T$STDT
      ,coalesce(b.t$tdat,c.t$tdat,d.t$tdat,e.t$tdat,f.t$tdat) as t$tdat
      ,coalesce(b.t$qanp,c.t$qanp,d.t$qanp,e.t$qanp,f.t$qanp) as t$qanp
      ,a.t$pric
      ,coalesce(b.t$disc,c.t$disc,d.t$disc,e.t$disc,f.t$disc) as t$disc
      ,coalesce(b.source,c.source,d.source,e.source,f.source) as Source 
      from  table(edi.ftAllPlCatalogs(:comno,cpls)) where t$cuno=:cuno a
        left join table(edi.ft30ciDiscounts(:comno,:cpls,:cuno)) b on a.t$item=b.T$item and a.t$cuno=b.t$cuno
        Left Join table(edi.ft31CPGDiscounts(:comno,:cpls,:cuno))  c on a.t$cpgs=c.t$cpgs
        left Join table(edi.ft31Cdiscounts  (:comno,:cpls,:cuno)) d on d.t$cpgs is null
        left join table(edi.ft33plpgDiscounts(:comno,:cpls)) e on d.t$disc is null and a.t$cpgs=e.t$cpgs
        left join table(edi.ft33PlDiscount(:comno,:cpls)) f on e.t$disc is null 
      Order by A.T$CPGS, a.t$item;';
  Open c for SQ using
      comno,cpls,cuno
      ,comno,cpls,cuno
      ,comno,cpls,cuno
      ,comno,cpls,cuno
      ,comno,cpls
      ,comno,cpls;
   LOOP
    fetch c into r;
    exit when c%notfound;
    pipe row(r);
  END LOOP;
  close c;
end;
```

Comment: You received the default error message from oracle.  There is a syntax error somewhere in your very long query.  I suggest starting again and taking baby steps.  Write a line and run it.  Then add a little bit more and run it.  Every time you get an error, you'll know it was caused by the last thing you added.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think the syntax

`t$stdt=coalesce(b.t$stdt,c.t$stdt,d.t$stdt,e.t$stdt,f.t$stdt)`

is valid in Oracle.

Assuming that the meaning is to provide an alias for the expression, I believe the Oracle equivalent would be:

`coalesce(b.t$stdt,c.t$stdt,d.t$stdt,e.t$stdt,f.t$stdt) AS stdt`

(the AS keyword begin optional)

Comment: absolutly right..Thanks, Revised the code using 'AS' but now I get thisOLE DB provider "OraOLEDB.Oracle" for linked server "hades" returned message "ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended
ORA-06512: at "SAAP.EDI", line 1416".
OLE DB provider "OraOLEDB.Oracle" for linked server "hades" returned message "ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended
ORA-06512: at "SAAP.EDI", line 1416".
Msg 7320, Level 16, State 2, Line 2
Cannot execute the query "select * from table(edi.ftCustomerCatalog('010','145','000164'))" against OLE DB provider "OraOLEDB.Oracle" for linked server "hades".

Comment: @TonyP you don't need the semicolon ( `;` ) in the query string

Comment: @dave, I did with and without semicolon, no diff.

Comment: @TonyP The WHERE clause should follow the JOIN clauses.